# What's the point of the minimum field width when formatting a printf() string in C?

Tags: c

I've started reading C Programming: A Modern Approach and came across a section talking about the minimum field width when formatting and outputted string. Where %5d would display 4 characters and a space while being right justified with, let's say, an integer value that is in its thousands. Is there any use to this in the real world?

Example:

```
int i = 1234;
printf("%5d\n", i)
```

Expected output:

```
 1234
```

Comment: Yes, it allows you to line up columns when printing data in a tabular format.

Comment: `printf("%-5s %5d\n%-5s %5d\n", "ab:", 1001, "cde:", -1);`

Comment: @TomKarzes including building request messages meeting protocols that use fixed width formatting

Comment: Look up the documentation: You can change the filling character for number to '0', which is needed for example if your target requests that all number have 5 digits.